# Return false if any of the values in map is empty string or just blanks in java8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to write one-liner code that will return false if any of the values in the map is empty string or string of blanks. Thoughts?

Something like a advanced version of:

```
 Optional.ofNullable(map).filter(s -> s.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using your current approach:

```
boolean present = 
        Optional.ofNullable(map)
                .filter(x -> 
                        x.values().stream()
                                  .noneMatch(s -> s != null && s.trim().isEmpty()))
                                  .isPresent();
```

or simply:

```
boolean present = map != null && 
                  map.values()
                     .stream()
                     .noneMatch(s -> s != null && s.trim().isEmpty());
```

Comment: `s != null && s.isEmpty() ||` is redundant in the "more simply". If the string is empty, `trim()` returns the same string. But then `s.trim().isEmpty()` is neater in the second case.

Comment: @AndyTurner my bad for not reading the doc. I had thought `s.trim()` would always construct a new string object hence the check prior to calling it. nevertheless, you're correct and edited. appreciated :).

Comment: Off topic: don't know if you remember that question the other day about `b ? Integer.valueOf(0) : Long.valueOf(0)`, yielding the funny type? I wrote an [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ConditionalExpressionNumericPromotion) check for that - and actually found a bug in openjdk! I just mention it because I remember you commenting on the question that it was a really strange thing.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
return map.values().stream().noneMatch(v -> v != null && v.trim().isEmpty());
```

---

`v.trim().isEmpty()` is true iff the string is blank (`""`) or contains only whitespace.

[`noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) is true if no items in the stream (of values, here) satisfy the predicate. It's short-circuiting, so this is nice and efficient too.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check for the presence of empty strings, use

```
public static boolean containsNoEmptyString(Map<?,?> map) {
    return !map.containsValue("");
}
```

If you want to check for blank strings, I recommend

```
public static boolean containsNoBlankString(Map<?,String> map) {
    return map.values().stream().noneMatch(Pattern.compile("^\\s*$").asPredicate());
}
```

Operations like `s.trim().isEmpty()` do more than just checking for the desired property, they *construct a new string*. Creating new objects is not a problem per se, i.e. the regex match operation may also create objects behind the scenes, but the problem with the string creation of the `trim()` operation is that it bears a potentially expensive operation that scales with the input string.

There are no problems with empty strings or blank strings, as applying `trim()` will just return a cheap empty string. Likewise, there is no problem with strings that do not start or end with spaces, as then, `trim()` simply returns the original string.

The problem is that there might be strings which are not blank, but start or end with spaces. Then, `trim()` will create a new string with a *copy* of the entire string, except for the leading and trailing spaces, and that may be an arbitrary amount of characters. So the potential costs of this operation, performance and memory-wise, scale with the size of the strings.

In contrast, the overhead of the regex match operations is fixed. Only the actual matching depends on the length of the string, but even there, the regex match operation is cheaper. `trim()` searches for white-space at the beginning and after identifying the first non-white-space character it will search for white-space at the end of the string, to strip both. The regex matching will start at the beginning, but *stop* at the first non-white-space character, as then, the string is not blank. Only for truly blank strings, the costs will be on par, but there will be at most one blank string checked for a map, as that’s the stop condition, after having checked an arbitrary number of non-blank strings.

Comment: is this another myth about regexes being *that* expensive? Every time I use at work - I get a comment in code reviews this being expensive and it takes quite a lot of time to write correct and good benchmarks to prove otherwise...

Comment: @Eugene there is a simple rule of thumb. If you are going to do the same match operation multiple times, the additional preparation overhead likely will pay off afterwards. If in doubt, you can refactor the code to keep the precompiled `Pattern` in a `static` variable. Then, there is no reason why plain character comparisons should be slower when being done within the regex rather than a plain `String` operation. But even for a literal text search, [the preparation may pay off when doing the match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)…

Comment: that's at least the second time I watch a video about Boyer Moore (at least youtube says so), I assume it was still you who pointed me towards it... thank u, I do have a good argument in reviews right now!

Comment: @Eugene and actually, it should be the other way round. If your colleagues claim that your code was slow (due to using regex or whatever), *they* should be in charge to prove that. It might be even the case that a particular use of the regex engine is indeed slower than an alternative, but only on a negligible scale. The only reason to avoid it, should be when a benchmark/profiling proves that there is a performance problem truly induced by the use of the regex engine. As said, even then, it should be checked whether the preparation or an inefficient pattern is the cause, as both can be fixed…

Comment: I mean,  both can be fixed without stopping to use the regex engine.

Comment: good point and thank you for this; unfortunately this will never be the case where I am *at the moment*, but this is nevertheless a good question to ask when potentially moving to a new place